# Add registry: from ListBox to DataSet

Tags: delphi, listbox, dataset

I need to read two names from two different ListBox and associate this two names into a registry in DataSet. But, on the DataSet, the relationship are made by ID of the person, the name it's only a LookUp.

In my mind:

**Step 1:** Read the name and get the person ID.

**Step 2:** On event BeforeInsert of navigator, insert the ID in respective column.

Importante Informations:

- The relationship is from employee ID and manager ID.
- I am new in Delphi.

**Question:**

The implementation is failing, because the DataSet is in a different Unit from the ListBox, and I don't know how fix this problem without changing the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the unit containing the `DataSet` to the `implementation` uses clause of the unit that has the `ListBox`. If your `TDataSet` is `DataSet1` in a `TDataModule` named `dmMyData` in `MyDataMod.pas`, you'd do it something like this (see my **Note** below):

```
unit Main;

interface
  uses Forms, ....

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    Button1: TButton;
  protected
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    ...
  public
    ...
  end;

implementation

uses
  MyDataMod;   // Use the actual unit name, of course

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1) then
    if (ListBox2.ItemIndex <> -1) then
    begin
      // Access the dataset however you need here
      dmMyData.DataSet1.Insert;
    end;
end;
```

**Note** The better way, of course, is to separate the data from the UI, and create a procedure that would take the employee and manager info as parameters and handle all of the processing of that information there. That's a totally different issue than what you asked here, however.

Comment: Can you make a example of procedure that handle with parameters of employee and manager? I guess my problem now is not in the different units, but in the procedure I make.

I'm failing on get the names from a ListBox, associate that name to an ID, and than export this ID to DataSet.